# Angle sensor to measure the stepper motor shaft rate of rotation

Tags: stepper-motor

what Kind of Sensor that i can use to know how much angle stepper Motor shaft has rotated ?
Actually,I am thinking to rotate my stepper Motor at 1 rpm and my stepper Motor shaft Diameter is 8mm and length would be around 20 mm. I am using this stepper Motor in very sensitive Case that is the reason why iam  going to use microstepping Driver also.
Can anyone help me out form this query?
And ,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What did your web recherche reveal? I would expect at least a few manufacturers providing such sensors. Over 20 years ago I was working on such a sensor that produces absolute angles, but had to abandon it before it was finished. It had a resolution of 1/1000 of a degree, giving 360'000 parts per revolution.

Comment: If skipping steps isn't a concern, you can just count the step pulses you sent to your driver.
If it is, you'd usually use an optical encoder.

Comment: You can get absolute position rotary encoders that are made for this task. Google them.

Comment: The datasheet on the stepper motor contains the number of steps per rotation. So divide 360⁰ by the number of steps to get the angle per step. Then it just a case of counting steps. The only issue is finding the 0⁰ position, so you'd need to add some mechanism to __home__ the motor. Either manually, of with something like a limit switch.

Comment: Thank you for your Wonderful Response @Majenko ,I am going to run  at 1 rpm and I wanted to see the exact Speed while ist rotating and i wanted to know the exact angle is it possible with this ,and sorry for asking again:)